# checking if child input is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, children

So... I need to check if input checkbox is checked, and i know in what element it is, but ,for some reason, when i try "find()" or "children()" it's giving me an error (not a function) :/
html:

```
  <ul id="playlist">    
<li class="current-song hińska_muzyka"><input type="checkbox" checked class="hińska_muzyka_ch"/><a href="somme_src">name</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
alert($("#playlist li")[currentSong].children('input').checked);
alert($("#playlist li")[currentSong].find('input').checked);
```

In js both not working :/
I can't figure out what i should do to make it work.
And as you can probably deduce currentSong is my var that contain index of li with currently playing song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready
  if($("#playlist li").children('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){ // check tat checkbox is  checked or not?
   alert('checked'); // if yes then alert message
  }
});
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($("#playlist li").children('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
    alert('checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="playlist">    
  <li class="current-song hińska_muzyka">
    <input type="checkbox" checked class="hińska_muzyka_ch"/><a href="somme_src">name</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note:-

jQuery library needed before script code to make it work.

if script code added on top of then page then wrapping of code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});` is needed, but if script is added at the bottom of the page then it's not needed.

***And as you said that you finally got the correct answer based on above help which is:-***

```
$(".playlist li").each(function (i){ 
   if($(this).index()==currentSong){ 
      alert($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':ch‌​ecked')); 
      return false; 
   } 
});
```

Comment: ok, but i have to check an particular #playlist li input, and this is giving me (i think) the first one. And this is where i have problem.

Comment: you need to first convert `id='playlist'` to `class='playlist'` for all li, because id need to be unique per element and then you have to apply `.each` to check each li check-boxes.

Comment: ok, i finally got this:
`$(".playlist li").each(function (i){
   if($(this).index()==currentSong){
    alert($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'));
    return false;
   }
  });` umm it's not readeable, but works :D

Comment: @Vivent glad that you did something your own. glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<ul id="playlist">    
<li class="current-song hińska_muzyka">
  <input type="checkbox" checked class="hińska_muzyka_ch"/> 
  <a href="somme_src">Tpain</a>
</li>
<li class="current-song hińska_muzyka">
  <input type="checkbox" checked class="hińska_muzyka_ch"/> 
  <a href="somme_src">Chris Brown</a>
</li>
```

This will go for your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#playlist li input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                alert("checked");
            }
        });
     });
 });
```